# Does the Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum spell block summoning creatures into the warded area?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes, summoning

If you secure an area with the [*Mordenkainen's private sanctum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/private-sanctum) spell and choose the effect:

> Planar travel is blocked within the warded area.

Does this prevent summoning creatures into the area via spells like [*infernal calling*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/infernal-calling) (XGtE, p. 158)?

Planar travel, in this instance, could either mean "willingly moving between planes" or "moving between planes under any circumstance", and I don't know which is meant by the spell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The text says "Planar travel is blocked" with no other exceptions or restrictions, which means that **both of your specified scenarios would be blocked**, regardless of how or why it is happening. Therefore, as long as the summoning spell is summoning a creature from another plane, it would be blocked.

For example, *Instant Summons* would be blocked if it summoned the object from another plane, and most of the *Conjure X* spells would be blocked as they pull creatures from another plane.

Comment: Conjure X with the exception of *conure elemental* and *conjure minor elementals*, I think, since they do not state that you're summoning them from their respective plane.

Comment: None of the *conjure X* spell descriptions mention a plane, including the *conjure elemental/minor elementals* spells. Neither does *[Drawmij's] instant summons*.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how one's summoning works. If your DM allows you to pull the spirits from the surrounding area and form them into creatures, then summoning could work. RAW, it prevents summoning.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! You are making a valuable point and I would love to see you support it by citing rules and offering insight into how that scenario worked out at your table. Expertise is a requirement for this kind of answer on [subjective answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As Akixkisu said, your answer would be improved if you supported it by citing the rules and/or your own experience.