# Are there spells that prevent a magic user from using a summoning spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning

Which spells can stop a magic-user from using a summoning spell either by stopping the spell effect or by stopping the magic user from casting?

I can only think of two:  [Counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) and [Anti-Magic Field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field)

Are there any others?

Comment: See [Does the Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum spell block summoning creatures into the warded area?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134417/does-the-mordenkainens-private-sanctum-spell-block-summoning-creatures-into-the)

Comment: Is this for preventing a hostile caster from casting spells?  Specifically, will the caster be a willing or unwilling target for the spells?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adapted from [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/171218/what-ways-exist-to-prevent-counterspell-from-being-cast/171221#171221).

**Make the enemy unable to cast spells**

- [Animal Shapes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animal-shapes) (PHB, pg. 212) Requires willing target.
- [Antimagic Field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field) (PHB, pg. 213) 10 foot sphere around your self, requires position management.
- [Feeblemind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind) (PHB, pg. 239) Int save, resave after *30 days*.
- [Mass Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mass-polymorph) (XGtE, pg. 160) Wisdom save.
- [Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) (PHB, pg. 266) Wisdom save.
- [True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) (PHB, pg. 283) Wisdom save.
- [Illusory Reality](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#SchoolofIllusion) <sup>1</sup> (PHB, pg. 118), combo with [Minor Illusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/minor-illusion), see footnote.
- [Confusion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/confusion) (PHB, pg. 224) Wisdoms save, 20% chance to act normally even on a failed save.
- [Dominate Beast](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-beast) (PHB, pg. 234) Wisdom save. Requires beast creature type. The only beast with spellcasting I'm aware of is [Traxigor](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/traxigor), an archmage that was polymorphed into an otter from the adventure *Descent into Avernus*. Traxigor does not have any summoning spells on his statblock, but the DM may choose to put some there. This will also work on an 18th level NPC druid while in Wildshape form.
- [Dominate Monster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-monster) (PHB, pg. 235) Wisdom save.
- [Dominate Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-person) (PHB, pg. 235) Wisdom save, only works on humanoids.
- [Slow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow) (PHB, pg. 277) Wisdom save, possibility for a single turn delay.
- [Sleep](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sleep) (PHB, pg. 276)
- [Imprisonment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/imprisonment) - Slumber (PHB, pg. 275) Wisdom save.
- [Hold Person](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hold-person) (PHB, pg. 251) Wisdom save, requires humanoid.
- [Hold Monster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hold-monster) (PHB, pg. 251) Wisdom save.
- [Power Word Stun](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/power-word-stun) (PHB, pg. 267) Target must have 150 or fewer hitpoints.
- [Psychic Scream](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/psychic-scream) (XGtE, pg. 163) Intelligence save.
- [Divine Word](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/divine-word) (PHB, pg. 234) Charisma save. 40 or fewer hit points, target is blinded. 30 or fewer, target is also stunned. 20 or fewer, target is dead.
- [Reality Break](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/reality-break) (EGtW, pg. 189) Wisdom save. 20% chance to stun, 20% chance to blind, 60% chance to take a lot of damage but still be able to act.
- [Contagion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contagion) (PHB, pg. 227) Requires three failed Constitution saves. Inflicts a disease of your choice, three of which are applicable here.
- [Symbol](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/symbol) (PHB, pg. 280) Lots of applicable options here.
- [Hypnotic Pattern](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hypnotic-pattern) (PHB, pg. 252) Wisdom save.
- [Tasha's Hideous Laughter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hideous-laughter) (PHB, pg. 280) Wisdom save.
- [Modify Memory](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/modify-memory) (PHB, pg. 261) Wisdom save.
- Many of the *conjure something* spells require you to target an unoccupied space you can see, so inflicting the [blindness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Blinded) condition with [Blindness/Deafness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blindness-deafness) (PHB, pg. 219) or [Sunbeam](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sunbeam) (PHB, pg. 279) would do the trick if the summoning spell required sight. Additionally, [Darkness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) (PHB, pg. 230), [Fog cloud](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fog-cloud) (PHB, pg. 243), and [Cloudkill](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cloudkill) (PHB, pg. 222) would prevent the caster from seeing any unoccupied spaces within range.
- All of the summoning spells have verbal components, so the [Silence](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/silence) (PHB. pg. 275) will prevent them from being cast.
- [Leomund's Tiny Hut](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/leomunds-tiny-hut) (PHB, pg. 255) If the caster is inside the hut, they cannot target a point outside the hut, and creatures summoned inside the hut cannot leave. Casting time of 1 minute and the hut is quite small.

**Stopping their spell**

- [Counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell) (PHB, pg. 228) Requires an ability check.
- [Temporal Shunt](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/temporal-shunt) (EGtW, pg. 189) Wisdom save.

**Preventing Planar Travel**

- [Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mordenkainens-private-sanctum) (PHB, pg. 262) Casting time 10 minutes.
- [Forbiddance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/forbiddance) (PHB, pg. 243) Casting time 10 minutes

**Sending the caster to another plane**

- [Imprisonment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/imprisonment) - Hedged Prison (PHB, pg. 252)
- [Maze](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/maze) (PHB, pg. 258) Just works.
- [Banishing Smite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishing-smite) (PHB, pg. 216) Damage must reduce target to 50 of fewr hit points.
- [Banishment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment) (PHB, pg. 217) Charisma save.
- [Plane Shift](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/plane-shift) (PHB, pg. 266) Must hit on a melee spell attack, and target must fail a Charisma save.

And finally, you can cast *wish* to cast any spell in this answer, or appeal to the DM with something like “I wish you wouldn’t do that.”

---

<sup>1 to equip them with armor they are not proficient in, if you accept "[Would forcing armour on a wizard using an illusion spell and Illusory Reality 'harm' them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/126213)"</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### Any spell that kills the magic user

All of the spells in [Thomas' list](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/175893/are-there-spells-that-prevent-a-magic-user-from-using-a-summoning-spell/175894#175894) apply.

In addition, it would seem that any spell that kills the magic-user, or at least incapacitates them by putting them to 0 hit points, would achieve the goal of "stopping the magic user from casting". Dead magic-users don't cast spells.

Which spell this could be would depend on how many hit points the magic-user has. As [find familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar), a lowly first level spell, qualifies as summoning, and wizard-magic users start out with only 6 hit points, even spells that deal modest damage technically qualify. And of course the magic-user might already be hurt and only have a single hit point left, at which point *any* spell capable of dealing damage would apply.

That list of spells is really to long to usefully enumerate here. Some high level, high impact options likely to work well on the dinky hit point totals of magic-users are

- [Disintegrate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/disintegrate) (Dexterity save or expected 70 damage)
- [Power Word Kill](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/power-word-kill) (no save, up to 100 hp instant death)
- [Meteor Swarm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/meteor-swarm) (expected 70 damage even on successful Dexterity save, twice that otherwise)

Comment: "Dead magic-users don't cast spells". Hah! Just make sure you finish the job though, because almost-dead magic-users are a whole different story.

Comment: You're not wrong, but this seems like an unhelpful frame challenge.

Answer (score -1):

### *Hallow*

Given you are defending an area, and with enough time to pre-cast, *[Hallow](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hallow)* is pretty good.  It's not a perfect answer, but it has a lot recommending it.  As a default effect,

> First, celestials, elementals, fey, fiends, and undead can't enter the area

'Can't enter the area' presumably means both being summoned within it and appearing outside and physically entering.  The list of creature types blocked will stop *most* summoning spells, and is effective at shutting down: *Conjure Celestial, Conjure Elemental, Conjure Fey, Conjure Minor Elementals, Conjure Woodland Beings, Summon Celestial, Summon Elemental, Summon Fey, Summon Fiend, Summon Undead, Summon Greater Demon,* and *Summon Lesser Demons*.

Unfortunately, the list is not comprehensive and *Hallow* will not be a hard stop to *Conjure Animals, Summon Aberration, Summon Beast, Summon Construct, Summon Draconic Spirit,* or *Summon Shadowspawn*.

However, you have not exhausted your *Hallow* yet.

> Second, you can bind an extra effect to the area.

Select 'all creatures' to be the targets, and the 'extra effect' to be:

> **Extradimensional Interference**. Affected creatures can't move or travel using teleportation or by extradimensional or interplanar means.

This is not a hard block, but it will force all of the creatures not stopped initially to make a Charisma save when they first attempt to enter the area, which may eliminate most of them if the summoner does not recognize that the area is warded by a *hallow* spell and tries to summon them within it (as opposed to summoning them outside and then just walking them in, which this will not prevent).  Your spell DC against a Charisma save will eliminate most Animals, Aberrations, Beasts, and Constructs, further winnowing the field.  Unfortunately you are still going to be be moderately vulnerable to Draconic Spirits and Shadow Spawn.

#### *Leomund's Tiny Hut*

Assuming a DM [allows a caster](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/173808/does-conjuration-work-from-inside-leomunds-tiny-hut) to summon while inside the [*hut*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-hut), creatures summoned to the inside cannot leave, and the caster cannot summon creatures to appear outside.  Creatures summoned outside cannot enter.

#### Damage

Conjuration / Summoning spells in general demand concentration, so any way you have of [breaking the caster's concentration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74432/in-what-ways-can-a-spellcasters-concentration-be-disrupted) will end the effect of the spells.

Damage is the simplest route.  *[Spirit Guardians](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spirit-guardians)* and then rushing the caster is great - it is a sustained area of effect, no hit roll required, and damage even if they make the save.  (*Spirit Guardians* followed by *Sanctuary* is even better, to protect you from whatever they have summoned so you can keep your own concertation on the *Guardians* up).

Spells that repeatedly damage them, forcing multiple concentration saves each round are also good, such as *[scorching ray](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scorching-ray)*, which can deliver multiple independent sources of damage on each cast.