# Does Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum prevent me from opening a Portable Hole?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, planes

Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum says that

> planar travel is blocked within the warded area

and the portable hole's description states that

> the cylindrical space within the hole exists on a different plane.

Does this mean that portable holes' contents can't be accessed within a private sanctum?

Comment: Highly related (dupe?): [Does Private Sanctum prevent Rope Trick from being cast?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171851/52137)

Comment: Related at least: "[Does Private Sanctum prevent Rope Trick from being cast?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171851)" and "[Is the "pocket dimension" a familiar goes into a demiplane or an extradimensional space?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105928)" and "[Does the Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum spell block summoning creatures into the warded area?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134417)" and "[Is there a difference between a plane of existence and an extradimensional place?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138107)"

Comment: Note that I closed your question as a duplicate of another as I feel that entering the space created by *rope trick* and entering the space created by a Portable Hole are sufficiently similar. If you feel this is not the case (that there is some significant or nuanced difference) feel free to [edit] or leave a comment saying so

Comment: @Medix2 I added this question instead of just settling for the rope trick answer for two reasons: 1) Portable holes specifically say that the space is on a different plane, instead of being "extradimensional" and 2) I couldn't find anything that specifically talked about portable holes. Related, yes. Duplicate? Dubious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Probably, but it probably isn’t a big deal.

It’s up to the DM to decide what exactly constitutes *planar travel*, but I think it pretty clear that traveling to the inside of a portable hole, which is a different plane, is planar travel. As you have observed, the description of a portable hole says:

> the cylindrical space within the hole exists on a different plane.

That said, your game isn’t going to break if players are allowed to access their extra dimensional storage inside of the bounds of the sanctum. Discuss it with your DM and with your table.

Comment: It's a big deal for DMs looking to do something about the "everyone hops in the portable hole, invisible sneak sneaks into place, everyone hops out" infil plan. It's clever once and useful later, but it shouldn't always work. Granted, our party did this to itself by asking the question.